# increment a column in the table based on user input values

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a stored procedure that would increment one of the column in the table by 1, everytime either of the country code (AXX,XPP,CGG) is given as user input, depending on the already existing country code value

```
ID  CountryCode
1   AXX
2   AXX
1   XPP
3   AXX
4   AXX
2   XPP
```

My code below fetches a value that reads the ID like

```
ID
1
2
3
4
...
...
```

```sql
Create procedure [dbo].[sp_Incremental]
@code varchar(50)
as
begin
    declare @IDbigint
    set @ID= 1 ;
    begin try
        Select @ID=count(ID)+1 from [Incremental_tbl]
        Begin
            Insert into [Incremental_tbl] values (@ID,@code)    
        End
end
go
```

Comment: FYI the prefix `sp_` is reserved, by Microsoft, for **S**pecial / **S**ystem **P**rocedures. It should *not* be used for User Procedures. Doing so comes with a performance cost and the risk of your Procedure simply not working one day after an update/upgrade. Either use a different prefix or (possibly better) no prefix at all. [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Comment: This feels like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info). Why are you not just using an `IDENTITY` or a `SEQUENCE`?

Comment: Another vote for not reinventing the wheel. This is done nice and tidy with either IDENTITY or SEQUENCE. And those already handle all of the really challenging edge cases for concurrency and all the pain that comes along with getting that kind of stuff wrong.

Comment: ummm... that did not really work accordingly.. The ID is not expected to be displayed sequentially.. rather the ID should come like ID CODE
1 UK
2 UK
1 EU
2 EU
3 EU
3 UK

It would increment for the seperate "CountryCode" sequentially as an when it is entered by the user Any other feedback to this !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this SP :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p_Incremental @code VARCHAR(50)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO Incremental_tbl (ID, code) 
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(ID), 0) + 1, @code
FROM   Incremental_tbl
GROUP  BY @code;
GO
```

But, do not forget that, in concurrency acesses, same values can occur for the ID !

Comment: I really recommend using explicit locks here if this is the solution you are going to go down.

Comment: @larnu Better will be to use SERIALIZATION ISOLATION LEVEL instaed of explicit locks